# ¿Dónde se crea forms.py?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

¿Si tengo una formulario de un questionario que toma los datos de un modelo, y al pulsar en enviar formulario se guardan los datos en otro modelo, ¿Dónde hay que crear forms en la app del primer modelo o en la app del segundo modelo?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En mi opinion debes crearlo en la app que contiene el modelo que tiene los datos a mostrar en el formulario. Puedes usar un forms.ModelForm y la creación del mismo sera bastante sencilla. En el formulario que creaste puedes sobreescribir el metodo **save** para manejar el guardado de los datos en el otro modelo de esta forma si ocurre un cambio en el segundo modelo solo debes cambiar el código dentro de **save**.

Comment: Me encantaría ver un ejemplo en algún lado. ; ) Gracias Noel Molina.